# Allow space in words Regex

Tags: php, regex

Regex:`([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@((?1))`

Test string: `abc def@abc`

result:

```
Match 1: def
Match 2: abc
```

How to allow spaces in regex?
I want the result to be:

```
Match 1: abc def
Match 2: abc
```

Comment: Do you understand how `[a-zA-Z0-9]` works? I'd recommend reading something like http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Yes it has to match either upper or lowercase a-z or 0-9. Thanks for the link I will take a look :D

Comment: I got it i had to add a space inside [a-zA-Z0-9 ] :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add the space character inside your character class `[]` in order to be matched also.

```
$text = 'abc def@abc';

preg_match_all('/[a-z0-9 ]+/i', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc def
    [1] => abc
)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9 ])+$/i", $str)
```

want `@` also match try

`preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9@ ])+$/i", $str)` (i haven't test this)